# Colocar reticências na paginação do mixItUp

Tags: jquery

Tenho este script de paginação do `mixItUp`, que funciona normalmente.

```
// To keep our code clean and modular, all custom functionality will be contained inside a single object literal called "buttonFilter".

var buttonFilter = {
   // Declare any variables we will need as properties of the object

   $filters: null,
   $reset: null,
   groups: [],
   outputArray: [],
   outputString: '',

   // The "init" method will run on document ready and cache any jQuery objects we will need.

   init: function(){
      var self = this; // As a best practice, in each method we will asign "this" to the variable "self" so that it remains scope-agnostic. We will use it to refer to the parent "buttonFilter" object so that we can share methods and properties between all parts of the object.

      self.$filters = $('#Filters');
      self.$reset = $('#Reset');
      self.$container = $('#Container');

      self.$filters.find('fieldset').each(function(){
         self.groups.push({
            $buttons: $(this).find('.filter-api'),
            active: ''
         });
      });

      self.bindHandlers();
   },

   // The "bindHandlers" method will listen for whenever a button is clicked. 

   bindHandlers: function(){
      var self = this;

      // Handle filter clicks

      self.$filters.on('click', '.filter-api', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var $button = $(this);

         // If the button is active, remove the active class, else make active and deactivate others.

         $button.hasClass('active') ?
            $button.removeClass('active') :
            $button.addClass('active').siblings('.filter-api').removeClass('active');

            self.parseFilters();
      });

      // Handle reset click

      self.$reset.on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         self.$filters.find('.filter-api').removeClass('active');

         self.parseFilters();
      });
   },

   // The parseFilters method checks which filters are active in each group:

   parseFilters: function(){
      var self = this;

      // loop through each filter group and grap the active filter from each one.

      for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
         group.active = group.$buttons.filter('.active').attr('data-filter') || '';
      }

      self.concatenate();
   },

   // The "concatenate" method will crawl through each group, concatenating filters as desired:

   concatenate: function(){
      var self = this;

      self.outputString = ''; // Reset output string

      for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
         self.outputString += group.active;
      }

      // If the output string is empty, show all rather than none:

      !self.outputString.length && (self.outputString = 'all'); 

      console.log(self.outputString); 

      // ^ we can check the console here to take a look at the filter string that is produced

      // Send the output string to MixItUp via the 'filter' method:

      if(self.$container.mixItUp('isLoaded')){
         self.$container.mixItUp('filter', self.outputString);
      }
   }
};

// On document ready, initialise our code.

$(function(){
   // Initialize buttonFilter code

   buttonFilter.init();

   // Instantiate MixItUp

   $('#Container').mixItUp({
      pagination: {
         limit: 12 //4
      },      
      controls: {
         enable: true // we won't be needing these
      },
      callbacks: {
         onMixFail: function(){
            //alert('No items were found matching the selected filters.');
         }
      }
   });    
});
```

Mas ao executar, a paginação fica:

```
< 1 2 3 15 16 17 >
```

Seria possível colocar reticências no meio, para ficar assim:

```
< 1 2 3 ... 15 16 17 >
```